# Installing node 16 in Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL) gives me node 14

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, emscripten

I installed node 16, on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL on Windows10) using these commands:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And it gets the right package

> Unpacking nodejs (16.13.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
> Setting up nodejs (16.13.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...

But somehow, I get node 14

> $ node -v
> v14.15.5

I had nodejs installed already before I tried to upgrade to 16 but I am pretty sure the installer removed it.

I tried to remove the package `nodejs` and installagain , I ran `apt autoremove`, I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` and there is only the `node_16.x` PPA...

What did I miss? Where is that node 14 coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... Turns out it was *emscripten* who had installed another *NodeJS* in its own app folder and was setting that in the env.

I just deleted the `node` directory in the `emsdk` folder and it's working.

**Edit**: I had compilation issues on MacOS when I removed the `node` directory because emscripten was using system libs that were probably not matching its expectations. So I had to restore it (using `emsdk install SOME_VERSION`).

Comment: This is an open topic/issue: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/4848